# Prove that $\sqrt[n]{a^n+x}=a+\frac{x}{na^{n-1}}-r$ ,$a>0$,$x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Prove that

$\sqrt[n]{a^n+x}=a+\frac{x}{na^{n-1}}-r$ ,$a>0$,$x>0$

given $0$$<$$r$$<$$\frac{n-1*x^2}{2n^2*a^{2n-1}}$.

What I did.

$\sqrt[n]{a^n+x}=a(1+\frac{x}{a^n})^\frac{1}{n}=a(1+\frac{1}{n}*\frac{x}{a^n}+\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{n}*\frac{1-n}{n}*(\frac{x}{a^n})^2)$ = $a+\frac{ax}{na^n}+\frac{a*(1-n)*x^2}{2n^2*a^{2n}}$ = $a+\frac{x}{n*a^{n-1}}+\frac{x^2(1-n)}{2n^2*a^{2n-1}}$

Now remainder is in Lagrange form.

$0$$<$$r$$=$$\frac{1-n}{2n^2*a^{2n-1}}x^2$ $<$ $\frac{(n-1)*x^2}{2n^2*a^{2n-1}}$

Because $n>1$,$r<\frac{(n-1)*x^2}{2n^2*a^{2n-1}}$ but I am getting $r<0$ can you please say where I made mistake.

Comment: Please don't use $*$ for multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The second term should be
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n}(\frac1{n}-1)(\frac{x}{a^n})^2
=-\frac{n-1}{2n^2}(\frac{x}{a^n})^2
$.